# Pass function from Scala.js to Javascript function?

Tags: scala.js

I've defined function in Scala.js like this:

```scala
val myFunction: js.Function1[js.Array[String], Boolean] = (data: js.Array[String]) => true
```

And also defined Javascript function on the page:

```
function callFunction(inputFunction){
  console.log(inputFunction(["10"]))
}
```

When I make a call from Scala.js:

```scala
GlobalScope.callFunction(myFunction)
```

I got error:

> Uncaught TypeError: inputFunction is not a function

What I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Definition of the `GlobalScope`:

```scala
@JSGlobalScope
@js.native
object GlobalScope extends js.Any {
  def GlobalScope.callFunction(someFunction: (js.Array[String]) => Boolean): Unit = js.native
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `GlobalScope` and its method `callFunction`?

Comment: @sjrd I've added definition of GlobalScope to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `callFunction` in `GlobalScope` is erroneous. It asks for a `js.Array[String] => Boolean`, which is a *Scala* function from `js.Array[String]` to `Boolean`, not a JavaScript function. When you call it, even if you give it a `js.Function1[js.Array[String], Boolean]` (which is correct), the Scala type system will insert an implicit conversion from `js.Function1` to `scala.Function1` to conform to the expected type. But then of course the JavaScript code in `callFunction` receives a Scala function and is not happy with it.

The solution is to fix the definition of `callFunction` to take a `js.Function1`:

```scala
@JSGlobalScope
@js.native
object GlobalScope extends js.Any {
  def callFunction(someFunction: js.Function1[js.Array[String], Boolean]): Unit = js.native
}
```